# jquery mixed with css using variables, underscore and hyphens

Tags: jquery, css

So I have a css file that looks like this:

```
.textbox{
 position: fixed;
 width: 225px;
 }
```

then I have a JQuery method that looks like this:

```
function textbox(name) {
...
$(".textbox_" + name).text();
...
$(".textbox-" + name).text();
    }
```

I have no idea what the underscore and the hyphen do, because there is nothing in the css file that has an underscore or a hyphen. I don't really understand how you can pass variables in css.

Comment: Do you have any of the HTML that would correspond with this?  Since the `_` and `-` are within the class name, this is saying there's another div that's called something like `.textbox_test` or something like that

Comment: `$(".textbox-"name).text()` won't compile, you need a `+` in there.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume name == `foo`. If I understand you right, you're comparing your CSS and JavaScript code and noticing the similarity between these identifiers:

- `.textbox`
- `.textbox-foo`
- `.textbox_foo`

So you wonder: Is `foo` some kind of parameter or [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) that combines with the `.textbox` class in your CSS? What's the relationship here?

**Answer: There is none.** `textbox`, `textbox-foo`, and `textbox_foo` are all completely different HTML/CSS class names. Hyphens and underscores are perfectly valid as part of an identifier in CSS, so these three classes are as different as if they were named `abc`, `def`, and `ghi`.

So there are no variables being passed to your CSS. You're right, CSS doesn't have variables. All you see are different classes that have similar names, but are unrelated as far as the browser is concerned.

The jQuery call `$(".textbox_" + name)` is JavaScript, though, and you *can* pass variables in JavaScript. Using jQuery, this code finds a sequence of HTML elements with class name `textbox_foo`, where `foo` is whatever name you passed to the `textbox` function. It won't touch elements of class `textbox` or `textbox-foo`, unless they also have the `textbox_foo` class.

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UxkE8/)**

As for the JavaScript `textbox` function, there's no way to tell what it does without seeing the rest of it. My guess, based on other jQuery plugins I've seen, is that it manipulates new or existing textboxes in the page according to the `name` parameter you feed it. It probably adds styles and behavior to them, and in the process it dynamically adds HTML elements with the class `textbox-foo` and/or `textbox_foo`. The similar names are probably to help you understand the generated HTML source.

Answer (score 0):

That function is dynamically getting text from textboxes. So if you pass a string parameter like `"blah"` to that function:

```
textbox("blah");
```

Then the [jQuery is getting the text inside of the element](http://api.jquery.com/text/) which has the class `textbox_blah` or `textbox-blah`.

If those elements do exist you can use CSS on the class names to style them.